# If one number then a different number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have two columns of numbers on a data page, over 500 pairs. And I need a formula for the working page that will insert the second number in “column B” if the first number is in “column A”.  So if my data sheet looks like:

```
A       B
1500    1
1600    5
1800    7
1501    6
```

So then if there is a 1500 in “column A” on the working sheet I get a 1 in “Column B” and so on.

---

THIS IS WHAT I’M TRYING TO DO: I have a list of congressman (and some of them repeat) and I’m looking for something that will fill in the matching distract number in the corresponding cell, so I can eliminate the risk of human error in manual filling them in.

Comment: I was trying to do a if then formula, but it will be too long, and i have a second data set that has 20,000 number pairs to do later.

Comment: Maybe the question is unclear, but you want to take a number, search for it and return its pair? vlookup.

Comment: Have a look here for details of what @Raystafarian means.http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/excel2007/excel2007s7p10.html

Comment: I would recommend `INDEX`+`MATCH` instead of `VLOOKUP` because it's more flexible, doesn't require a strict data format, faster, more immediately understandable later (especially if referencing a table). [Learn how](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/) to use it and never go back to `VLOOKUP`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear, but let's assume the data looks like this

```
A    B    C    D
Adam 21   Bill
Bill 22   Dick
Carl 23   Carl
Dick 24   Adam
```

And you want to take the value in column C, find it in column A and return the value in Column B. This is [vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65)

```
D1 =VLOOKUP(C1,$A$1:$B$4,2,0)
D2 =VLOOKUP(C2,$A$1:$B$4,2,0)
D3 =VLOOKUP(C3,$A$1:$B$4,2,0)
D4 =VLOOKUP(C4,$A$1:$B$4,2,0)
```

Now your table looks like this

```
A    B    C    D
Adam 21   Bill 22
Bill 22   Dick 24
Carl 23   Carl 23
Dick 24   Adam 21
```

---

There are other ways to do this like -

```
=INDEX($A$1:$B$4,MATCH(C1,$A$1:$A$4,0),2)
```

or

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$4,MATCH(C2,$A$1:$A$4,0))
```

or even go old-school (read: don't)

```
=LOOKUP(C1,$A$1:$A$4,$B$1:$B$4)
```

Or even this ridiculous way

```
=INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(C1,$A$1:$A$4))
```

My point being, in the comments I mentioned vlookup, which a quick google search would have explained to you and you would be well on your way to becoming a spreadsheet wizard.

Answer (score -1):

Have one column for each if statement:

```
+---+------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|   |  A   |      B      |         C          |         D          |         E          |         F          |
+---+------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 1 | 1500 | =MAX(C1:F1) | =IF($A1=1500,1,"") | =IF($A1=1600,5,"") | =IF($A1=1800,7,"") | =IF($A1=1501,6,"") |
+---+------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Which produces this:

```
+----+------+---+---+---+---+---+
|    |  A   | B | C | D | E | F |
+----+------+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1 | 1500 | 1 | 1 |   |   |   |
|  2 | 1600 | 5 |   | 5 |   |   |
|  3 | 1800 | 7 |   |   | 7 |   |
|  4 | 1501 | 6 |   |   |   | 6 |
|  5 | 1700 | 0 |   |   |   |   |
|  6 | 1501 | 6 |   |   |   | 6 |
|  7 | 1600 | 5 |   | 5 |   |   |
|  8 | 1500 | 1 | 1 |   |   |   |
|  9 | 1500 | 1 | 1 |   |   |   |
| 10 | 1800 | 7 |   |   | 7 |   |
| 11 | 1800 | 7 |   |   | 7 |   |
+----+------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If the number isn't one in the list (i.e. not `1500`,`1600`,`1800` or `1501`) then it puts in the number 0, as in row 5.

You can optionally hide the extra columns.

Comment: You read the "over 500 pairs" bit of the question? Vlookup is the way to go. It also allows for changes to be made to the 'non-working; part of the sheet without any alterations to the 'working' part. Plus allows for scalability. You way would be too labour intensive

Comment: How to make such tables? whats the markdown for that?

Comment: @Tim - But you gave him a load of separate if statements

Comment: How is `=vlookup` not a formula?

Comment: @Prasanna I use [this](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) website, you can format as Unicode, HTML or SQL (ASCII).

Comment: @Raystafarian I didn't know it existed...? I answered with what I know, please down vote if it isn't useful...

Comment: @Joe Yes, formula. That was how I knew how to do it :)